# Question about the finite subgroups of F*

Tags: field-theory

Suppose $F$ is any field. Let $G$ and $H$  are two subgroups of $F^*$ of order $n$. Then is it true that $G=H$?

For finite field this is true. Is this true for arbitrary fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is true. For every $a\in G$, $a^n=1$. So every $a\in G$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^n-1\in F[x].
$$
The same holds for every $b\in H$. Because $|G|=|H|=n$, $G$ and $H$ consist of all the roots of $f(x)$ and so $G=H$.

Comment: Note that this implicitly uses the fact that $x^n-1$ has at most $n$ roots in $F$.